# react-native run-android: usb debugging not working

Tags: android, react-native

I have installed the development environment for react native on Windows 7 using the instructions [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html).

I have installed the following packages:

- Python 2.7
- node 4.2.4
- npm 2.14.12
- react-native-cli 0.1.10
- react-native 0.18.0-rc
- Android SDK

I can generate a skeleton project using the command `react-native init Test`.

However, when I execute the command `react-native run-android`, the following error occurs: Unable to install `path\to\app-debug.apk`.

The device, a Samsung Galuxy running Android 5.0.1, is connected to my PC and USB debugging on the phone has been enabled. When I type `adb devices` the phone appears in the list.

I can download the apk to the phone manually using the command `adb install`. However, when I run the app, a red screen appears with the error "Unable to download js bundle." This error persists even after I do the following:

- Start the local development server using `react-native start`
- Executing the command: `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`
- On the phone, setting the debug server host and port to `localhost:8081`

**Update**: I have solved one problem by downloading gradle to version 1.2.3 as described [here](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.23/docs/android-setup.html). However, the red screen still appears with the error *Unable to download js bundle*.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are working fine. for this problem have added the IP address in device Setting server host. one more thing your machine and device should have on same network.